# How to run command once line is detected from ADB Logcat?

Tags: android, macos, shell

As the titles says, I need to run some command/script after a particular log is printed from ADB Logcat, how can I go about it?
Have tried things like

```
adb logcat | grep whatever | while read line do echo 'got it' done
```

but it doesn't work.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
adb logcat |grep --line-buffered 'whatever' | while read ; do echo "got it" ; done
```

Or using `awk` :

General syntax :

```
tail -f <log file> | awk '/<string to look for>/ { system("<shell command>")}'
```

Command for your case :

```
adb logcat |awk '/whatever/ { system("echo \"got it\"")}'
```